# Django redirect, reverse

Tags: python, django, redirect

How can i do it so the user after editing the post doesn't get redirected to homepage but to the detail view of the post they just edited

**My views.py**

```
from . models import Post
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import DeleteView, UpdateView, CreateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

def home(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'pages/index.html', {'posts':posts})
    
def detail(request, slug):
    post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'pages/detail.html', {'post':post})
    
class edit(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'pages/edit.html'
    fields = ['title','image','body']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('pages:homepage')
    
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        handler = super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        user = request.user
        post = self.get_object()
        if post.author != user:
            raise PermissionDenied
        return handler
```

**my models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from A_Tech_Blog.utils import unique_slug_generator

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=300)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_images', default='default.jpg')
    time_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    body = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title} -- Author={str(self.author)}'
        
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-time_created']
        verbose_name_plural = 'Posts'
        
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('pages:detail', args=(self.slug))
        
        
def slug_generator(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = unique_slug_generator(instance)
        
pre_save.connect(slug_generator, sender=Post)
```

I want to be able to edit the post then get directed to the detail view of the post instead of being redirected to the web app homepage

Comment: Override [`get_success_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.get_success_url) and base the result on the post.

Comment: Are you sure your form is valid?

Comment: my form is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `get_success_url()` method in your view

Something like this should work

```
class edit(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    ...
    # success_url = reverse_lazy('pages:homepage')

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('pages:detail', args=[self.slug])
```

Comment: i am using the slug for the urls. Will it be the same?

Comment: Yes. You didn't give your urls but if you use a slug you can probably have something like return reverse('pages:detail', args=[self.slug])